# If $f_n\to f$ in measure then $|f|$ is finite a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a complex valued function. If $f_n\to f$ in measure then $|f|$ is finite a.e.

I need this fact to prove another result, but I cannot show this. How can I show this? I would greatly appreciate any help.

So the reason I got to this question is while solving this problem. Assume $f_n \to f, g_n \to g$ in measure. If $\mu(X)\lt \infty$ then $f_ng_n \to fg$ in measure.

Below is the solution to the problem and it uses the fact that $\mu(\bigcap E_N)$ is a null set, which means that $|f|,|g|$ are finite a.e.(I think it's wrong to argue that $\bigcap E_N=\emptyset$. Isn't it possible for $|f|$ to assume infinte values at some points?

[image]

Comment: This is not true if you don't assume anything on $f_n$.

Comment: You need as hypothesis that $f_n$ is finite a.e for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Since you allow functions to assume $\infty$ as a value, why can't it be $f_n=f\equiv \infty$ ?

Comment: I have that $f_n$ are complex valued measurable functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your definition of convergence in measure allow $f_n$ and $f$ to be infinite on a set of positive measure?  If so, what about $f_n = f$?

EDIT:  Let $A = \{x: |f(x)| = \infty\}$.  By definition of convergence in measure, there is $N$ such that for $n > N$, 
$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < 1$ except on a set of measure $< \epsilon$.  But $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < 1$ is impossible if $|f(x)| = \infty$ and $f_n(x) \in \mathbb C$.  Thus $m(A) < \epsilon$.  Since this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, $m(A) = 0$.

Comment: I have $f_n$ as a complex valued function, so it won't have infinite norm on any $x$.